# Docker Alpine, Celery (worker and beat) fail with PermissionError when using non-root user

Tags: docker, dockerfile, celery, alpine-linux

I'm trying to run a Flask app with Celery (worker + beat) on Docker Alpine using docker-compose.

I want it to run with a non-root user `celery` in my Docker container.
The flask app is building ok and works, but my celery containers are failing with this error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/platforms.py", line 543, in maybe_drop_privileges
    _setuid(uid, gid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/platforms.py", line 564, in _setuid
    initgroups(uid, gid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/platforms.py", line 507, in initgroups
    return os.initgroups(username, gid)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

My Dockerfile:
I tried to add `RUN chown celery:celery /etc/group` thinking that was the issue but it's still failing

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk update && \
    apk add build-base python3 python3-dev libffi-dev libressl-dev && \
    cd /usr/bin && \
    ln -sf python3 python && \
    ln -sf pip3 pip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN addgroup celery
RUN adduser celery -G celery -s /bin/sh -D

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/celery/ && chown celery:celery /var/log/celery/
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/celery/ && chown celery:celery /var/run/celery/
RUN chown celery:celery /etc/group  # added to try fixing the issue

USER celery

ENV FLASK_APP=flask_app
WORKDIR app/
COPY flask_app flask_app
```

My docker-compose:

```
(...)
celeryworker:
    build: .
    command: celery -A flask_app.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --uid=celery --pidfile=/tmp/celeryworker-shhh.pid

celerybeat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A flask_app.tasks beat --loglevel=INFO --uid=celery --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat-shhh.pid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers from @Shashank V and @Kine were really relevant and helpful but still had some issues afterward.

After doing some research, I finally made it works with the following configuration

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.11.0

RUN apk update && \
    apk add build-base python3 python3-dev libffi-dev libressl-dev && \
    ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
    ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 usr/bin/pip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/celery/ /var/run/celery/
RUN addgroup app && \
    adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --ingroup app --no-create-home app && \
    chown app:app /var/run/celery/ && \
    chown app:app /var/log/celery/

USER app

ENV PATH="/home/app/.local/bin:${PATH}"
WORKDIR app/

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt\

COPY flask_app flask_app

ENV FLASK_APP=flask_app
```

**docker-compose**

```
 (...)
 celeryworker:
   build: .
   command: >
     celery -A shhh.tasks worker
     --loglevel=INFO
     --logfile=/var/log/celery/celeryworker-shhh.log
     --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celeryworker-shhh.pid

 celerybeat:
   build: .
   command: >
     celery -A shhh.tasks beat
     --loglevel=INFO
     --logfile=/var/log/celery/celerybeat-shhh.log
     --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-shhh.pid
     --schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule  # specify schedule db in a loc where app has read/write access
```

Comment: Your approach looks good, but
can anyone explain, i am running my celery docker-compose service from non root user in ubuntu , but anyhow it takes root user in container, it ran smoothly for 3 months,,....all of a sudden on updating image it gives me warning to run as non root user and container keeps restarting....

Answer (score 3):

You should do like that

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/celery/ /var/run/celery/
RUN useradd -G root celery && \
    chgrp -Rf root /var/log/celery/ /var/run/celery/ && \
    chmod -Rf g+w /var/log/celery/ /var/run/celery/c && \
    chmod g+w /etc/passwd

...
RUN chmod a+x /start.sh
USER celery
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

You should create user celery firsts. Then, add this user into group root. After that you need set write permission for this folder you need to put logs and /etc/passwd.
You also need to have one script to add your user into /etc/passwd

```
#!/bin/bash
#
if [ `id -u` -ge 10000 ]; then
    echo "celery:x:`id -u`:`id -g`:,,,:/home/web:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd
fi
```

Comment: I'm using an Alpine image where `useradd` needs to be `adduser`. Although I wanted to create a specific group as well for this user. Found a working solution after doing some research. But this helped! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You have to be root user if you want to use `--uid` or `--gid` argument. Try removing these arguments.

Comment: Cheers, indeed this makes sense as the command is executed from the created container with the current user. Also I still had some issues afterwards to access the beat scheduler db. Found a solution after doing some research. But this helped a lot!